# pandas - How can I add row's as a column when creating a dataframe from a list of dicts?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dicts that are in a specific order, I can convert them to dataframes but I'd like to make the rowId as a identifier.

Here's my code and where I'm stuck:

```
priceHistory
[{'Apple': 1.27, 'Oranges': 2.92, 'Pears': 2.05},
 {'Apple': 1.12, 'Oranges': 3.33, 'Pears': 1.72},
 {'Apple': 1.22, 'Oranges': 4.52, 'Pears': 2.31},
 {'Apple': 1.37, 'Oranges': 5.93, 'Pears': 2.81},
 {'Apple': 1.5, 'Oranges': 5.77, 'Pears': 3.66},
 {'Apple': 1.59, 'Oranges': 5.24, 'Pears': 3.35},
 {'Apple': 1.29, 'Oranges': 4.97, 'Pears': 4.02},
 {'Apple': 1.53, 'Oranges': 6.03, 'Pears': 5.22},
 {'Apple': 1.86, 'Oranges': 8.4, 'Pears': 7.04},
 {'Apple': 1.61, 'Oranges': 10.33, 'Pears': 5.98}]
priceHistorydf = pd.DataFrame(priceHistory)
priceHistorydf
Apple   Pears   Oranges
0   1.27    2.05    2.92
1   1.12    1.72    3.33
2   1.22    2.31    4.52
3   1.37    2.81    5.93
4   1.50    3.66    5.77
5   1.59    3.35    5.24
6   1.29    4.02    4.97
7   1.53    5.22    6.03
8   1.86    7.04    8.40
9   1.61    5.98    10.33
```

As you can see the order is correct and it has row numbers. but I need those identifers in a separate column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `reset_index`, then the index become one column and can be treat as id

```
priceHistorydf = priceHistorydf.reset_index()
```

Or

```
priceHistorydf ['ID'] = np.arange(len(priceHistorydf ))
priceHistorydf 
Out[13]: 
   Apple  Pears  Oranges  ID
0   1.27   2.05     2.92   0
1   1.12   1.72     3.33   1
2   1.22   2.31     4.52   2
3   1.37   2.81     5.93   3
4   1.50   3.66     5.77   4
5   1.59   3.35     5.24   5
6   1.29   4.02     4.97   6
7   1.53   5.22     6.03   7
8   1.86   7.04     8.40   8
9   1.61   5.98    10.33   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the index to a new column.

```
priceHistorydf['ID'] = priceHistorydf.index
```